# Run-time error '1004': SaveAs Method of object '_Workbook failed

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following code to save an updated workbook.

```
Private Sub cmdSaveUpdatedWB_Click()

On Error GoTo Err_cmdSaveUpdatedWB_Click

    gwbTarget.Activate   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    gwbTarget.SaveAs txtUpdWorkbookName.Value, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    frmLoanWBMain.Show
    gwbTarget.Close
    Set gwbTarget = Nothing

    gWBPath = ""
    gWBName = ""

    lblWorkbookSaved.Enabled = True
    cmdUpdateAnotherWorkbook.Visible = True

Exit_cmdSaveUpdatedWB_Click:

    Exit Sub

Err_cmdSaveUpdatedWB_Click:

    MsgBox "The following error occurred inthe [cmdSaveUpdateWB_Click] event handler." & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & "Error descriptioin: " & Err.Description

    Resume Exit_cmdSaveUpdatedWB_Click

End Sub
```

As noted in the title, the SaveAs operation fails. I've determined that the failure is a result of having the workbook to be saved losing the focus. I can step through the code and get the error. Once the error is generated, selecting Debug in the error message box and then pressing F5 to run the code will result in the workbook saving correctly. Placing Debug.Print statements before and after the Activate method of the worbook to be saved indicates that the active wokbook is the workbook containing the code and the form used to update the workbook. Placing a print statement in the Immediate wondow that prints the ActiveWorkbook.Name will result in printing the name of the workbook to be saved - gwbTarget.Name. Pressing F5 then runs the code correctly.
  I have been unable to figure out why the workbook to be saved loses the focus. I placed delays, multiple activation statements, local variables to use for the workbookto be saved, and for the name of the workbook to be saved. Any help or ideas as to why this is happening and how to fix it will be greatly appreciated.

I did make some changes. The code is listed below...

```
Private Sub cmdSaveUpdatedWB_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_cmdSaveUpdatedWB_Click

Dim wbSave As Workbook

    Set wbSave = gwbTarget

    gwbTarget.Activate

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'''''''    gwbTarget.SaveAs txtUpdWorkbookName.Value, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

    wbSave.SaveAs fileName:=txtUpdWorkbookName.Value, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    frmLoanWBMain.Show
    gwbTarget.Close
    Set gwbTarget = Nothing

    gWBPath = ""
    gWBName = ""

    lblWorkbookSaved.Enabled = True
    cmdUpdateAnotherWorkbook.Visible = True


Exit_cmdSaveUpdatedWB_Click:

    Set wbSave = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Err_cmdSaveUpdatedWB_Click:

    MsgBox "The following error occurred inthe [cmdSaveUpdateWB_Click] event handler." & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & "Error descriptioin: " & Err.Description

    Resume Exit_cmdSaveUpdatedWB_Click

End Sub
```

I've changed the code to more closely resemble the suggestion below. The listing is below, along with the variable definitions as they were upon entry into the program. The Excel code is running in a Citrix environment which may effect timing but shouldn't have any other effect on code execution.

I deleted the other code versions for brevity. The following code is what has worked. The key issue is that the workbook to be saved must be the active workbook when the SaveAs method is invoked.

Private Sub cmdSaveUpdatedWB_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_cmdSaveUpdatedWB_Click

Dim wbSave As Workbook
Dim wsActive As Worksheet
Dim sNWBName As String

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

sNWBName = txtUpdWorkbookName.Value

Set wbSave = gwbTarget
wbSave.Activate
Set wsActive = wbSave.ActiveSheet

wbSave.SaveAs fileName:=sNWBName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

frmLoanWBMain.Show
gwbTarget.Close
Set gwbTarget = Nothing

gWBPath = ""
gWBName = ""

lblWorkbookSaved.Enabled = True
cmdUpdateAnotherWorkbook.Visible = True
```

Exit_cmdSaveUpdatedWB_Click:

```
Set wbSave = Nothing
Exit Sub
```

Err_cmdSaveUpdatedWB_Click:
Dim strErrMsg As String

```
strErrMsg = "Error Number: " & Err.Number & " Desc: " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & _
        "Source:" & Err.Source & vbCrLf & _
        "Updating Workbook: " & vbCrLf & "      " & gwbTarget.Name & vbCrLf & _
        "Selected Worksheet: " & gwsTrgSheet.Name & vbCrLf & _
        "Active Workbook: " & vbCrLf & "      " & ActiveWorkbook.Name & vbCrLf & _
        "Worksheet: " & ActiveSheet.Name & vbCrLf & _
        "Code Segment: cmdSaveUpdatedWB_Click event handler"

RecordErrorInfo strErrMsg

Resume Exit_cmdSaveUpdatedWB_Click
```

End Sub

Comment: where do you declare `gwbTarget`? Is it the same workbook the code is stored in?

Comment: It's a global variable that is declared in a code module that is contained in the workbook that contains the code.

Comment: Firstly you can remove your `activate` statement - you don't need that. Check if your `gwbTarget` is defined by putting a break point on the `SaveAs` line and checking your locals when the code stops there. My guess is that `gwbTarget` is `Nothing`

Comment: @CallumDA that would be a runtime error 91 on the `.Activate` call. But yeah, no need to `.Activate` it at all.

Comment: @Mat'sMug...one day I'll know all the different error codes off by heart!

Comment: I've tried commenting out the activate statement and the results are the same. Doesn't work if it's run straight through but clicking Debug on the error message, then F5 runs the code correctly. Moving between the worksheet that contains the code and then trying to reference the worksheet to be saved changes the focus  to the code workbook. The Activate is to retore the focus to the workbook to be saved.

Comment: I just went through the save process again with the Activate command commented out. The save as failed, gwbTarget was set to the workbook to be saved, the active workbook was the workbook that contains the code. Running the SaveAs after the error occurred, without restarting the program, executed the SaveAs correctly.

Comment: what is the value of `txtUpdWorkbookName.Value`?

Comment: That contains a string representing the full path and filename to be used for the updated workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you start with something like this

```
Private Sub cmdSaveUpdatedWB_Click()
    Dim gwbTarget As Workbook
    Set gwbTarget = Workbooks("workbook_name.xlsm") 'correct extension needed, workbook must be open

    wb.SaveAs Filename:=gwbTarget.Path, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

    MsgBox "Last saved: " & gwbTarget.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")
End Sub
```

Change one thing at a time to make it more like yours and hopefully it'll all work fine!

**Update**

As per the comments. If you are trying to open, update and close hundreds of workbooks. You can use this as a guide:

```
Sub ChangeWorkbooks()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wbPaths As Range, wbSaveFilenames As Range
    With Sheet1 'you will need to update this and the ranges below
        Set wbPaths = .Range("A1:A650") 'including file extensions
        Set wbSaveFilenames = .Range("B1:B650") 'including file extensions
    End With

    Dim i As Integer, totalBooks As Integer
    Dim wbTemp As Workbook

    totalBooks = wbPaths.Rows.Count
    For i = 1 To totalBooks
        Application.StatusBar = "Updating workbook " & i & " of " & totalBooks 'display statusbar message to user
        Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Open(wbPaths.Cells(i, 1), False)

        'make changes to wbTemp here

        wbTemp.SaveAs wbSaveFilenames.Cells(i, 1)
        wbTemp.Close
    Next i
    Set wbTemp = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Applicaton.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I made the references to the workbook to be saved local and used the format you suggested. I've run it a dozen times with different workbooks to be updated and eveything worked as it shoul. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Update - the problemis still happening, occasionally. Polite words can't express my excitement with this. At this point, clicking through the error message and then clicking the 'Save' command button again appears to be working.

Comment: Have you changed the code at all? Can you update the question with your new code (don't remove the original code though) if you have?

Comment: I have made a couple of chanages and added the updated code to the original question.

Comment: it doesn't seem like you've started with the code above and worked back to your code... without seeing your whole workbook I'm struggling to tell you what's wrong. All I can say is that the code above should always work. I don't think it will be creating an error but try removing `fileformat` and just ensuring the filename has the correct extension included

Comment: I understand what you are saying. The program will ultimately be used to updated 650+ workbooks each of which can have a variety of up to 15 worksheets. There will be 2 or 3 end users who are familiar with Excel but are not programmers. The idea is to automate the process as much as possible. I agree that the code as suggested should always work. However, I need to solve for the generic case thus the use of variables, global and local, for workbook, worksheet, filename, and path.

Comment: I updated the answer with something that might be more suitable. I tested it with four workbooks (I know... it's not 650) and it worked well. Give it a try!

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try.