# 1004: Method 'SaveAs' of object'_Workbook' failed

Tags: excel, vba, debugging

I am using this code and getting the SaveAs error:

```
Dim dirPath, Filename As String
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim newWb As Workbook

dirPath = "O:\Accounting\GFF-AP\OVERHEAD\LISA\VISA\Factoring Reports\"
Filename = ActiveSheet.Name & "_" & "_" & Format(Date, "mmddyy") & ".xlsx"

Worksheets("To Factor").Activate


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Sheets("To Factor").Copy

For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            Ws.Cells.Copy
            Ws.[A1].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
            Ws.Cells.Hyperlinks.Delete
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Cells(1, 1).Select
            Ws.Activate
        Next Ws
        Cells(1, 1).Select
    
Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=dirPath & "Factor Report_" & Format(Date, 
"mmddyy") & ".xlsx"

    ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

This has worked on other macros I have done.  Help!

Comment: It seems like there are quite a few previous questions with this name. Do any of these  help answer your question? [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42100279/14608750) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32140569/14608750) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51566372/14608750)

Comment: From reading the answers on those previous posts, I would guess that your problem is maybe that the SaveAs method is unable to follow your directory path. Is `dirPath` correct and are those folders accessible from the executing computer?

Comment: Yes it is.  VBA can be so frustrating :)

Comment: One of the problems was solved by specifying the [FileFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat) argument of SaveAs like `FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault`. It might not be enough to just add ".xlsx" to the end of the file name